# javascript in mobile web browsers

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-chrome, safari

I have this very simple html file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>alert("hi");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This usually runs fine in Firefox and Google Chrome on my laptop. But when I run this in Safari in an iPhone device and Google Chrome on an Android device, the JavaScript code doesn't run. That is, no alert appears. This is extremely unusual for me. Do we need to change JavaScript code when running on mobile devices? What should I do?

Comment: I just ran it in emulator and I don't see any issue. It is very unlikely. Could be some problem in those browsers that Javascript is disabled or something similar. Check from that perspective.

Comment: @hagrawal well, in android, google chrome's allow javascript on all sites are checked.

Comment: That is one possibility, like that there could be other possibilities, and it is very likely that you are facing the issue because of one such possibility because the code snippet you have provided is legitimate.

Comment: I'm assuming your pinging a server to get that webpage. Is your server listening for HTTPS?

Comment: @Ravenous I don't think so. I just sent the html file to my friend's facebook, then he downloaeded it in his device. Then he ran it and we found out the js code is not executing.

Comment: @morbidCode Try adding window ie `window.alert('Hi')`

Comment: @Ravenous ok, what does it do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Comment: @morbidCode hey come back and give me my imaginary internet points. I even added an inline snippet since you don't believe me. and more links http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert

Comment: @Ravenous ah, I do believe you, I just haven't tested it. I might have to clarify something later. But there's your internet point :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function(){
  window.alert('hi')
})()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script src="aJSfile.js"></script>
  
</html>
```

Add window to alert so that it says `window.alert('hi')` also see the core window functions supported by most browsers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert